# PayPal REST API returns INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR on execute payment

Tags: paypal, internal

When I get to the point where I'd normally execute a payment, I get an INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR back. This is the exact same code which worked a few weeks ago with no changes whatsoever. What should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are having some issues with API.It hasn't been working since 6pm EST